# How to evaluate integral: $ \int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(\ln(x))) \ dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help with integral below.I tried simple substitution $\ln(x)=y$ but I don't know how to deal with fact that $y$ belong to $[-\infty,0]$.I would be grateful for any hints.
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(\ln(x))) \ dx =\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{y}\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(y)) \ dy.$$

Comment: I'm guessing it's 0. I don't have a formal proof though

Comment: @miraunpajaro The result is $-\tanh{(\pi/2)}$

Comment: @Peter Foreman Oooops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next step could be:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{sgn}(\sin(\ln(x))) \ dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{y}\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(y)) \ dy=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\int_{-(k+1)\pi}^{-k\pi} e^{y}\,d y$$
Can you take it from here? BTW the final result is not zero!

Comment: thanks for hint i am trying to end it off but  i am not familiar with that series.

Comment: It's a geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: oh clear i am an idiot

Answer (score 2):

If you add $1$ to the integrand and subtract it out again, you get
$$ 2 \int_0^1 [ \sin(\ln x) > 0 ]\; dx - 1 $$
where $[\cdots]$ is the Iverson bracket, and the integral here is just the sum of the length of the intervals where $\sin(\ln x)$ is positive. These intervals are
$$ [e^{-2k\pi}, e^{-(2k-1)\pi}] \quad \text{for }k=1,2,3\ldots $$
so we want
$$ 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( e^{-(2k-1)\pi} - e^{-2k\pi} \right) -1 
= 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (e^{\pi}-1)(e^{-2\pi})^k -1 $$
The sum here is a geometric series.